# Настройки eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться! В  eclipse при присвоении переменной char любого номера символа юникода, вместо соответствующего символа выводится знак ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: код добавь, чтобы было понятней

Comment: package Lesson1;

public class PrimitiveDataTypes {
 public static void main(String[]args) {
 
 
 
 char c1 ='a';
 char c2 ='A';
 char c3 ='7';
 char c4 =' '; 
 char c5 = 570;
 
 
 
 
 System.out.println(c5);
 
 }                  // при любом значении в консоли выводит   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

поробуй так

```
   System.out.println('\u0045'); //E

//вывод всех символов
for (int i = 0; i < Character.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    System.out.print((char) i);

    if (i % 150 == 0) System.out.println();
}
```

если не выходит, скорее всего что-то с кодировкой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: package Lesson1;

public class Char {
 public static void main(String[]args) {
  System.out.println('\u0045'); //E

   }
 }
    В этом случае выводит Е , а если вставить весь код - бесконечное кол-во ????????????

Comment: В Intelij Idea такой проблемы нет.

Comment: ищи в настройках параметры кодировки

Comment: Спасибо, буду продолжать поиски)

Comment: в гугле напиши `eclipse ide изменить кодировку на utf 8`

Comment: Спасибо, братишка! Разобрался!   Window-Preferences-General-Workspase-Text file encoding     Снимаем галочку c Default, и ставим на Other  -  UTF-8

Comment: пожалуйста... если помог, можешь принять ответ, соответствующая галочка слева

Answer (score 0):

1. Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspase -> Text file encoding
2. Снимаем галочку c Default, и ставим на Other - UTF-8